# Keep printing same form until submit button is clicked

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi I'm quite new to php and I'm currently making a webpage similar to the ones used by supermarkets for stock management control as part of an assignment. I have the following form where the cashier would enter the product Id and the quantity of the item being purchased.

The form will then call another php file named cashsale.php which will take these inputs and update the tables in my database so that levels of stock on shelves in supermarkets are up to date with the new amounts (i.e. older qty - qty entered) and management can be advised when reorder is needed.

As it is the form works well, however I was advised to edit it in a way that a cashier can enter multiple products and quantities before submitting (i.e. the form will sort of show itself again) and allow the user to edit or remove any items before actually submitting the values to cashsale.php to manipulate the tables. I seem to be at a loss as to how this can be done.

I wanted to create a new button named "Add" which would display the form again, i.e. allow the user to check in more items, but I am confused as to how this can be done and also as to how I will be able to update tables then since I would be having more then just 2 inputs.

Can anyone help me on this please? Thanks in advance. The following is my html form:

```
center form action="cashsale.php" method ="post"

    Product ID: <input name= "id" type="int" > <br>
    Quantity:<input name="qty" type="int">

        <input type="button" name = "Add" onclick="add">

    <input type="Submit" name ="Submit" value = "Submit">

form center
```

I was not allowed to use html tags for form and center so I removed the < >. The following is some of the modifications done in the cashsale.php file just to give a clearer example.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shelfingdetails where prodId =' " .$id. " '");
    if (!$result){
    die (mysql_error());
    }
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $qtyOnShelf= $row ['QtyOnShelf'];
       $max=$row['max'];
       $newQtyShelf=$qtyOnShelf-$qty;

    }

    $update=mysql_query("UPDATE shelfingdetails SET QtyOnShelf ='". $newQtyShelf. "' where prodId = '". $id. "';");
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass an array. For this you have to generate the inputs with PHP or javascript (I'm gona use jQuery to keep the code nice and simpe).
If you use PHP:

```
// PHP
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']){
    //save data
} elseif(isset($_POST['Add']) && $_POST['Add']) {
    $max = (int)$_POST['max']
} else { $max = 1; }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
for($i = 0;$i < $max;$i++){
    ?>
    Product ID: <input name="id[]" type="int" > <br>
    Quantity: <input name="qty[]" type="int">
    <?php
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="max" value="<?= $i; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="Add" />

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If yo use Javascript:

```
//HTML
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <div id="add">
        Product ID: <input name="id[]" type="int" > <br>
        Quantity: <input name="qty[]" type="int">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="max" value="<?= $i; ?>" />

    <input type="button" name="Add" onclick="addRow();" />

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

// jQuery
function addRow(){
    $("#add").append("<br />Product ID: <input name='id[]' type='int' >" + 
                "<br />Quantity: <input name='qty[]' type='int'>");
}
```

you have to use `id[]` and `qty[]` to pass them as an array and with the add button generate as many of them as you need. Like so:

```
Product ID: <input name="id[]" type="int" > <br>
Quantity: <input name="qty[]" type="int"> <br>
Product ID: <input name="id[]" type="int" > <br>
Quantity: <input name="qty[]" type="int"> <br>
Product ID: <input name="id[]" type="int" > <br>
Quantity: <input name="qty[]" type="int">

<input type="button" name = "Add" onclick="add">
```

Then on the backand use for loop to save all the data.

```
$max = count($_POST['id']);
$id = $_POST['id'];
$newQtyShelf = $_POST['qty'];
for($i = 0;$i < $max;$i++){
    $update=mysql_query("UPDATE shelfingdetails
        SET QtyOnShelf ='". (int)$newQtyShelf[i]. "'
        WHERE prodId = '". (int)$id[i]. "';");
}
```

**I just wanted to show you the idea**, please don't use this specific code, because you should use mysqli instead of mysql and also mysqli_escape_string to make sure that the user not submits incorrect data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However what I'm getting confused in is in the add process where I generate as many of them as I need because I need to do this for an indefinite amount of times until user presses Submit. I tried to create and use a function named "add" which basically has the same form in it so that each time the add button is clicked the form is shown again, since on click the button calls this function. However I don't think the logic is right because when I click on Add nothing is happening.